# How to ignore spaces in an hash table?

Tags: string, perl, hash

when i run the hash table of my code, the table seems to take spaces into account (" : 405%"). How do we filter that? I tried to do it with the if condition but it doesn't seem to work.

```
my @g = ();
foreach my $e (@genres){ 
    my $genre = $e->as_text;
    @g = split(/[à| ]/,$genre);
    foreach my $e2 (@g){ 
        if ($e2 ne ("Genres:" or ' ') ) {
            $index{$e2}++;
        }
    }   
}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Normalize your keys by removing spaces from strings before using them as keys?

Comment: `$e2 ne ("Genres:" or ' ') ` That doesn't do what you want. Read up on perl syntax.

Comment: Please provide text, not images, as examples of input/output.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

As Shawn points out in the comments, this does not do what you think:

```
if ($e2 ne ("Genres:" or ' ') ) {
```

`ne` operates on two scalar values. Perl evaluates the `or` expression first: `'Genres:'` is true, so `('Genres:' or ' ')` yields `'Genres:'`. The condition filters out keys whose value is `'Genres:'`, but ignores `' '`.

You need to repeat the `ne` expression, using `and`:

```
if ($e2 ne 'Genres:' and $e2 ne ' ') ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> @g = split(/[à| ]/,$genre);
> foreach my $e2 (@g){ 
>     if ($e2 ne ("Genres:" or ' ') ) {
>         $index{$e2}++;
>     }
> }
> ```

A lot of this is pretty strange. Let's look at it a line at a time.

```
@g = split(/[à| ]/,$genre);
```

I'm not sure why you split on `[à| ]`. In particular, I don't see any instances of 'à' in your data. And by splitting on spaces, you get an array with three elements - the first is the genre, the second is always a colon and the third is the percentage.

> ```
> foreach my $e2 (@g){
> ```

Now you're walking your array. But I think you're only interested in the genre which is the first element of the array. So why look at the other two?

> ```
> if ($e2 ne ("Genres:" or ' ') ) {
> ```

This simply doesn't do what you think it does. You can only compare against a single values at a time. So this needs to be:

```
if ($e2 ne 'Genres:' and $e2 ne ' ') {
```

And, even then, the first expression will never match as none of your genre strings are "Genre" and none of them contain a colon (except, as we said earlier, the second element in `@g` will only contain a single colon.

I think that what you really want is this:

```
my ($genre_name, $percent) = split(/ : /, $genre);
if ($genre_name ne 'Genres' and $genre_name ne ' ') {
    $index{$e2}++;
}
```